# How to hide navigationBar shadow when user goes back to previous page (fast)

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

I want to hide the navigationBar shadow when the user goes back to the previous page. I do this with the Shown code, this works but extremely slow. The shadow disappears after one Second. I would like to do this immediately but have no idea how to do this or if it is even possible.

I have tried everything I know in functions like;
- viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, viewDidDisappear, [...]

```swift
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

````
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}```
````

Comment: @Jan In the answer I posted did you change the Hidden parameter to true ?